# Mongoose Sorting , .sort() queries output is not as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code for sorting episodes in ascending order using episodeNo is

```
const episodes = await Episode.find({anime: animeId}).sort({episodeNo: 1});
```

I think it should sort like 1, 2, 3, 4 but it's sorting like 1, 10, 11, 2, 3.

the JSON response is

```
      "id": "607dc50dc21368000414b378",
      "episodeNo": 1,
      "subtitle": false
    },
    {
      "id": "607dc50dc21368000414b381",
      "episodeNo": 10,
      "subtitle": false
    },
    {
      "id": "607dc50dc21368000414b382",
      "episodeNo": 11,
      "subtitle": false
    },
    {
      "id": "607dc50dc21368000414b383",
      "episodeNo": 12,
      "subtitle": false
    },
    {
      "id": "607dc50dc21368000414b379",
      "episodeNo": 2,
      "subtitle": false
    }
```

Comment: can you show your data?

Comment: @NinaScholz its already a Number in Model

Comment: It should work if its number type in database, you are probably missing something. make sure you are checking result from this variable `episodes`. and `{ anime: animeID }` i can not see this field in result.

Comment: @turivishal i have not returned it in result

Comment: anything you have printed or console. your result that you have added in your question.

Comment: got the answer, for some episode the episodeNo was string, and for some it was Int , now the error has solved.